# Very Basic JavaScript Callback/Closure Structure

Tags: javascript, callback, closures

I have this code:

```
var barfunction = function(foocallback){
    foocallback('bar');
}

var foofunction1 = function(){
    var foovar = 'foo';

    barfunction(function(barvar){
        /*huge amounts of code */
        console.log('f1' + foovar);
        console.log('f1' + barvar);
    });
}

foofunction1();
```

The anonymous inline function have access to foovar and it logs foo, bar. Now i want to move the huge amounts of code into its own function to keep foofunction readable, while maintaining a reference to foovar.

```
var barcallback = function(barvar){
  /* huge amounts of code */ 
  /* need foovar here */
  console.log('f2' + barvar);
}

var barfunction = function(foocallback){
    foocallback('bar');
}

var foofunction2 = function(){
    var foovar = 'foo';
    barfunction(barcallback);
}
```

What is the preferred solution for this scenario? Thank you

Comment: where did foocallback come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see only two solutions:

1. Add another parameter in the functions

   ```
   var barcallback = function(barvar, foovar){
     console.log('f1' + foovar);
     console.log('f2' + barvar);
   }

   var barfunction = function(foocallback, foovar){
       foocallback('bar', foovar);
   }

   var foofunction2 = function(){
       var foovar = 'foo';
       barfunction(barcallback, foovar);
   }
   ```
2. Make foovar a global variable in this context.

I think that solution 1 is better, because, if `barcallback` needs access `foovar`, then `foovar` should be one of its arguments.